# Can I install a Delta shower valve trim in place of a Moen?

Tags: plumbing

I currently have an old Moen shower valve, and in an ideal world I'd like to replace the trim with a Delta product. I've gathered that shower valves are brand specific, but short of completely replacing the valve and having to mess with the pipes behind the wall, is there any way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Would be helpful for you to include a pic of the Moen trim piece.

Comment: It's just a trim ring. If it fits, hides all the dirty bits, and doesn't allow water to leak, I don't see any reason not to.